# I am using context API in nextjs and its completely working fine but the typescript give the error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am currently working on a nextjs project where i need to use context API and the data coming from context API is completely fine but the typescript shows the error and I don't know what to do.

Error:

```
Property openDialogFxn does not exist on type Object.

Property state does not exist on type Object.
```

My Code:

In `AlertDialog.tsx` component

```
export const AlertDialog = ()=> {
const data = useContext(AlertDialogContext);
 console.log(data.openDialogFxn) // this line give error but value is accessible 
console.log(data.state) // this line give error but value is accessible
}
```

In `AlertContext.tsx`:

```
export const AlertDialogContext = createContext<null | Object>(null);
```

In `AlertDialogState.tsx`:

```
export function AlertDialogProvider({ children }: any) {

  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const openDialogFxn = () => {
    setCurrentValue(true);
  }

  const currentState = {
    state: currentValue,
    openDialogFxn
  }
  return (
    <AlertDialogContext.Provider value={currentState}>
      {children}
    </AlertDialogContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I just Want to know that why i am getting the typescript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you have passed in `null | Object` throws an error because neither of properties you are accessing (state, openDialogFxn) exist on the type definition for Object.

You can solve this by defining a type:

```
type TAlertDialogContext = {
  state: boolean;
  openDialogFn: () => void;
};
```

And passing that to your call to createContext:

```
const AlertDialogContext = createContext<TAlertDialogContext | null>(null);
```

Here's a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/key-does-not-exist-obj-ans-x775dt) with the updated code.

Hope this helps!